# Generate PDF from a list in SharePoint Online Modern Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf, spo

I need a solution for generating or converting a SharePoint list, document library or web page (HTML) to a PDF. Preferably saving it to a document library on the site, or at least sending it back to the user to open it in a client program like FoxIt or Adobe.

I have tested Muhimbi's solution, but this currently only supports Classic Mode (not Modern Sites).

Does anyone have knowledge of any 3rd party tool that supports this, or do we need to go and start coding it ourselves? :-P

Thanks, 
Frank

Comment: Hi Frank. Is my understanding correct that you are looking to convert a URL (of a list, library, or web page) to PDF, and not the content of a file stored in a list or library?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But in Modern, not Classic.

Comment: Modern view is very tricky at the moment as it is basically just JavaScript that renders a UI. In the next version of the Muhimbi PDF Converter we will support Modern View. We already have it working in house. Let's just say that it is less than trivial. Until the new version is released, the only option that I am aware of is to take the list data, insert the fields into some hand crafted HTML and then send that HTML to the PDF Converter. For an example see the second part of this blog post: https://goo.gl/YDLEVQ